# Event that fires when user clicks on the "New" button of an ASP.Net DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling, code-behind, html-select

In an ASP.Net VB.Net code-behind file, can you tell me what event fires that I can use to trap when the user clicks on the "New" button of a DetailsView at the time the DetailsView shows blank items such as DropDownLists, TextBoxes etc?

I need use this event handler to pre-select a value in a DropDownList obtained from a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the ItemCommand event. This is how to use it. I only know C# , but I think you get the hang of it.

Code behind:

```
protected void DetailsView_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "New")
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView" runat="server" OnItemCommand="DetailsView_ItemCommand" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try that event and let you know it I got it working.

Comment: I found that one is good for when the "Insert" button is clicked. Do you know which one is good for the "New" button?

Comment: Using ItemCommand was the way to go. Thank you. I tried to make the DropDownList select the value using the following code but the list was still not showing the data. Can you show me the extra needed coding to get it to work?             Case "New"
                Dim drpValue As DropDownList

                drpValue = DetailsView.FindControl("DropDownListClass")
                drpValue.SelectedValue = StrListValueToSelect